# Is it possible to count the sum of values found in multiple rows of tasks?

Tags: salesforce

I have a custom number field in tasks "Billable Hours" so time for each activity can be tracked, I am wondering if it is possible to create a formula that calculates the sum of "Billable Hours" from multiple tasks.

Thanks for any help or direction.

Answer (score 0):

If there is a Master-Detail relationship between your Task and the "Parent" object ( on which you will track the Sum ), you can create a Roll-up Summary field as Sum (Billable Hours). 
If the relationship is a look-up one then you need to write a trigger to maintain the above Sum on each parent.